# Image in Collection view cell is not updated when the image is downloaded asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift

The image in the collection view cell is not updated when the image is downloaded from the server. The image gets updated when the collection view is scrolled.

Every section of the table view has a collection view. And table view cell has datasource for the collection view.

```
extension OffersCell: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return photoViewModel.photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath)
        (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let photo = self.photoViewModel.photos[indexPath.row]
        (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.image = UIImage(named: "dummyImage")

        ImageDownloadManager.shared.downloadImage(photo, indexPath: indexPath) { (image, imageIndexPath, error) in
            if let indexPathNew = imageIndexPath, indexPathNew == indexPath {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Please find the image downloader class :

```
typealias ImageDownloadHandler = (_ image: UIImage?, _ indexPath: IndexPath?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

final class ImageDownloadManager {

    private var completionHandler: ImageDownloadHandler?
    lazy var imageDownloadQueue: OperationQueue = {
        var queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.name = "imageDownloadQueue"
        queue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        return queue
    }()

    let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    static let shared = ImageDownloadManager()
    private init () {}

    func downloadImage(_ photo: Photos, indexPath: IndexPath?, handler: @escaping ImageDownloadHandler) {
        self.completionHandler = handler
        guard let url = photo.getImageURL() else {
            return
        }
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: photo.id as NSString) {
            self.completionHandler?(cachedImage, indexPath, nil)
        } else {
                let operation = CustomOperation(url: url, indexPath: indexPath)
                if indexPath == nil {
                }
            operation.queuePriority = .high
                operation.downloadHandler = { (image, indexPath, error) in
                    if let newImage = image {
                        self.imageCache.setObject(newImage, forKey: photo.id as NSString)
                    }
                    self.completionHandler?(image, indexPath, error)
                }
                imageDownloadQueue.addOperation(operation)
        }
    }

    func cancelAll() {
        imageDownloadQueue.cancelAllOperations()
    }


}
```

Comment: please can you post downloadImage() method?

Comment: I think you should use library for image loading is best solution check link https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/best-image-download-extension-library-for-swift-3-cf64ec1f84a0

Comment: @AnasMehar I can use sd image for this but actually wanted to design my own image download manager which can have a custom implementation for different requirement.

Comment: Is your completionHandler called? Because it seems that there are at least a few places where it's not called: `guard let url = photo.getImageURL()`, in the else, it should be called, no? If you don't use a `UITableView`, but directly a UIImageView inside an empty UIViewController, does it work? Behavior make me think this (pure theory): it downloads the image, but doesn't call the completionhandler. When scrolling, it call the cached image that call the handler.

Comment: Yes, the completion handler is called and the image is updated once I start scrolling.

Comment: @Manav I edited my comment to add info/potential leads to search for you ;)

Comment: @Larme It works fine for table view and also for single image view but only fails in this scenario. Also ```guard let url = photo.getImageURL()``` is for checking if there is valid url for downloading the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define the class `CustomOperation`, but the problem seems to be in the method `downloadImage` of `ImageDownloadManager` where in the next line you set `self.completionHandler = handler`. Note that `ImageDownloadManager` is a singleton. This means that every operation you start replaces `completionHandler` of the singleton object with the new completion (I bet only the last cell was refreshed). The solution consists of elimination the property `completionHandler` and replacing the operation download handler with this

```swift
operation.downloadHandler = { (image, indexPath, error) in
    if let newImage = image {
        self.imageCache.setObject(newImage, forKey: photo.id as NSString)
    }
    handler(image, indexPath, error)
}
```

Note that it calls the handler of the context and not the stored property of the download manager

Here is a full working example with all the class and struct definitions. Adapt it as needed.

```swift
typealias ImageDownloadHandler = (_ image: UIImage?, _ indexPath: IndexPath?, _ error: Error?) -> Void

enum ImageDownloadError: Error {
    case badDataURL
}

class CustomOperation: Operation {

    var downloadHandler: (UIImage?, IndexPath?, Error?) -> () = { _,_,_ in }

    private let url: URL
    private let indexPath: IndexPath?

    init(url: URL, indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        self.url = url
        self.indexPath = indexPath
    }

    override func main() {
        guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: self.url) else {
            self.downloadHandler(nil, self.indexPath, ImageDownloadError.badDataURL)
            return
        }
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        self.downloadHandler(image, self.indexPath, nil)
    }
}

final class ImageDownloadManager {

    private var completionHandler: ImageDownloadHandler?
    lazy var imageDownloadQueue: OperationQueue = {
        var queue = OperationQueue()
        queue.name = "imageDownloadQueue"
        queue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        return queue
    }()

    let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    static let shared = ImageDownloadManager()
    private init () {}

    func downloadImage(_ photo: Photos, indexPath: IndexPath?, handler: @escaping ImageDownloadHandler) {
        //self.completionHandler = handler
        guard let url = photo.getImageURL() else {
            return
        }
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: photo.id as NSString) {
            //self.completionHandler?(cachedImage, indexPath, nil)
            handler(cachedImage, indexPath, nil)
        } else {
            let operation = CustomOperation(url: url, indexPath: indexPath)
            if indexPath == nil {
            }
            operation.queuePriority = .high
            operation.downloadHandler = { (image, indexPath, error) in
                if let newImage = image {
                    self.imageCache.setObject(newImage, forKey: photo.id as NSString)
                }
                //self.completionHandler?(image, indexPath, error)
                handler(image, indexPath, error)
            }
            imageDownloadQueue.addOperation(operation)
        }
    }

    func cancelAll() {
        imageDownloadQueue.cancelAllOperations()
    }
}

-------------------------------------------------------

struct Photos {
    let id: String
    let url: URL

    func getImageURL() -> URL? {
        return self.url
    }
}

struct PhotoViewModel {
    let photos: [Photos]
}

class PhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    private let photoViewModel: PhotoViewModel = PhotoViewModel(
        photos: [
            Photos(
                id: "kitty1",
                url: URL(
                    string: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/18/11/23/cat-4282110_960_720.jpg"
                )!
            ),
            Photos(
                id: "kitty2",
                url: URL(
                    string: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/23/20/08/cat-4358536_960_720.jpg"
                    )!
            ),
            Photos(
                id: "kitty3",
                url: URL(
                    string: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/28/13/15/kittens-1700474_960_720.jpg"
                    )!
            )
        ]
    )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photoViewModel.photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath)
        (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let photo = self.photoViewModel.photos[indexPath.row]
        (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.image = UIImage(named: "dummyImage")

        ImageDownloadManager.shared.downloadImage(photo, indexPath: indexPath) { (image, imageIndexPath, error) in
            if let indexPathNew = imageIndexPath, indexPathNew == indexPath {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    (cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you downloaded the image, you execute the instruction `(cell as! PhotoCell).imageView.image = image` on the main thread. But this does **not** redisplay your collectionView cell.
Also, `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` will normally not be called. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc) say

> The collection view calls this method before adding a cell to its
>   content.

It is however called, when you scroll in the cell, i.e. when it becomes visible. This is there reason why your image is displayed after the cell is scrolled in.

So my suggestion is:

- After downloading the image, update your collectionView data source
  so that `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` can configure the cell
  with the image.
- Call `reloadItems(at:)` with an array that contains only the index path of the updated cell.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the code to ```collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:``` but it did not resolve the issue. I will try ```reloadItems(at:)```. I have another question calling reloadItems will not be a loop as it will again call cellForItemAtIndexPath.

Comment: Hard to say what is wrong without the relevant code. Please have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started), and compare it to your implementation. This should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once image is downloaded is will not display unless collection view is scrolled as said by @Reinhard Männer

Instead you can go for the third-party SDKs(which fit your needs) for image downloading and caching in your app.

I will recommend to use [Kingfisher SDK](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) (developed in pure swift).

> It is easy to use and integrate. it does lot of thing like async. downloading, caching(on memory or disk), built-in transition animation when setting images, etc. and **it is popular too**

**For you'r problem it is one line code if you use `Kingfisher` SDK.**

For eg.

To load image asynchronously you can use following in `cellForRowAtItem:` method.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")
imageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```

What you all need to do is...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
    cell.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

    //I'm assuming photo is URL(in string) of Photo. if 'photo' is URL type then you can pass it directly in 'setImage' method.
    let photo = self.photoViewModel.photos[indexPath.row]

    let imgUrl = URL(string: photo)

    //It will download image asynchronously and cache it for later use. If the image is failed to downloaded due to some issue then "dummyImage" will be set in image view.
    cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: imgUrl, placeholder: UIImage(named: "dummyImage"))

    return cell
}
```

> Here you can remove cell `willDisplay:` method.